# How to enable and test implicit invocations?

Tags: actions-on-google

I'm adding invocations using DialogFlow but I have two questions:

1. After adding the implicit invocations in DialogFlow do I need to resubmit for production (and review) from the Google Actions Console? I suspect I do but would appreciate confirmation.
2. How do I test implicit invocations before submitting for production? The actions simulator seems to require explicit invocations.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](https://developers.google.com/actions/discovery/implicit) out for implementing implicit invocation.

1. You may need to resubmit for review if there are changes to the functionality in the app.
2. You can test the app on the mobile device in the Alpha or Beta version and see how it works. Just use the phrases as you would have put in an intent to trigger implicit invocation and Assistant should suggest you to use your app.